# Bootstrap 4: Override of font styles not working

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

I want to change the font size for `$small-font-size`.
To do so, I've added a custom partial with the following content:

```
$font-family-sans-serif: 'Fira Sans', 'Roboto', 'Inter', Arial, sans-serif;

$font-weight-light: 300;
$font-weight-normal: 400;
$font-weight-bold: 500;

$small-font-size: 0.625rem;
```

This partial is placed above the bootstrap SCSS files.

The strange part is, that the variable `$font-family-sans-serif` works fine.
But the other stuff gets ignored?!

I couldn't find the reason for that.

My main.css file shows the following:

```
b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder; // instead of 500}

small {
  font-size: 80%; // instead of 0.625rem}
```